# Sendmail Debug in Email Body

Tags: sendmail

Situation: Email being send from server hosting our production website. Email body contains routing of the email.

Question: Is this a sendmail.cf parameter? If so which parameter?

Example: From email body.

```
Received: by 10.76.162.102 with SMTP id xz6csp105065oab; Tue, 8 Jan 2013 00:14:35 -0800 (PST)
Received: from mail-la0-f53.google.com (mail-la0-f53.google.com [209.85.215.53]) by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id id8si106587047lab.0.2013.01.08.00.14.32 (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER); Tue, 08 Jan 2013 00:14:33 -0800 (PST)
Received: by mail-la0-f53.google.com with SMTP id fn20so132960lab.40 for <marion@efactor.com>; Tue, 08 Jan 2013 00:14:32 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.112.29.229 with SMTP id n5mr26704397lbh.130.1357632872532; Tue, 08 Jan 2013 00:14:32 -0800 (PST)
```